# PowerShell / Visual Studio Code: Update version of PowerShell in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.37.1 which is using PowerShell **v5.1.18362.145**. I went to GitHub to attain and install the latest PowerShell (**v6.2.2**) but, when I run `$psversiontable` in VS Code, it tells me it's still using the old version.

How do I get VS Code to use the latest PowerShell version I have installed?

Thank you.

**PowerShell admin window:**

[image]

Comment: VSCode docs read, "For Windows, there is a convenient shell selector located inside the terminal dropdown that lets you choose between several detected shells including Command Prompt, PowerShell, PowerShell Core."  Not true for me, though it was on my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/vscode-as-a-console-for-powershell-core-6-part-1-multiple-shells/).

This is the link address:  https://4sysops.com/archives/vscode-as-a-console-for-powershell-core-6-part-1-multiple-shells/

Answer (score 0):

code --install-extension PowerShell-6.2.2.vsix

Comment: Thanks @JohnMeek, I appreciate the response.  I get an error 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: Doesn't work, no clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest VS Code, just go to Settings and configure:

```
terminal.integrated.profiles
```

Just need to set this to Powershell instead of Default (or the appropriate directory).